# Dynamically add/remove row to table for phonebook app

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a simple project for work and my task is to create a simple, single page web app that takes input (name, and three different phone numbers), and adds them to a list, which can then be deleted.

This is what I've got so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRow() {
        var entry = getElementsById("form");
        var table = document.getElementById("list");
        var newRow = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell1.innerHTML = entry(0);
        cell2.innerHTML = entry(1);
        cell3.innerHTML = entry(2);
        cell4.innerHTML = entry(3);
    };

</script>       
</head>

<body>

<h1 id="title">Phonebook 1.0</h1>

<div id="welcome">
    <b id="welcomeText">Welcome to my single-page phone book application.</b>
</div>

<table id="list">
    <tr>
        <th class="header"><b>Name</b></th>
        <th class="header"><b>Home</b></th>
        <th class="header"><b>Work</b></th>
        <th class="header"><b>Cell</b></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form id="name"><input type="text" name="name"></form></td>
        <td><form id="home"><input type="text" name="home"></form></td>
        <td><form id="work"><input type="text" name="work"></form></td>
        <td><form id="cell"><input type="text" name="cell"></form></td>
        <td><button onclick="addRow()">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I just can't seem to get a row added. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `getElementsById("form");` - should be `document.getElementById` - singular on element - but you dont have any elements with ID of `form`?

Comment: @TheTurbobeef I added answer for your question, could you give  feedback, problem solved or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the table as a javascript variable (probably using `document.getElementById()`). Then, just add the code for the new row to its innerHTML. Also, you need to set the `id` attribute of your table to something so you can get it with `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement the solution here:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/